# Merge nested relations to an Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object, recursion

I have an array of objects that also contains array like this:

```
let array = [{"a": ["b", "c"]} , {"b":[ "d" ]}, {"e":[ "f" ]}]
```

I need to display it as Tree View and I need to get the output like below:

```
[
    {
        id : "a",  
        children: [ 
            {
                id: "b", 
                children: [{id: "d", children: [] }]
            },
            {
                id: "c",
                children: []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: "e",
        Children: [
            {
                id: "f",
                children: []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I tried to do it by creating an array of all the parents [a, b, e], and depth first search through the entire array but I could not get the correct output.

Can someone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: javascript is looking for variables, put a...f in doublequotes: 
`var array = [{"a": ["b", "c"]} , {"b":[ "d" ]}, {"e":[ "f" ]}]` - for starters...

Comment: Do a search for "javascript recursive(or recursion) tree"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this recursive approach:

```js
var array = [{ "a": ["b", "c"] }, { "b": ["d"] }, { "e": ["f"] }]
let object = {}
array.map(itm => Object.keys(itm).map(name => object[name] = itm[name]))

const treeView = (key, val) => {
  delete object[key]
  return {
    id: key,
    children: getChildrens(val)
  }
}
const getChildrens = (arr) => {
  let childrens = []
  return arr.map(itm => {
    if (object[itm]) {
      return treeView(itm, object[itm])
    }
    return { id: itm, children: [] }
  })
}
let res = Object.keys(object).map((val, idx) => {
  if (object[val])
    return treeView(val, object[val])
}).filter(e=>e)
console.log(res)
```